# How to use SWRevealVC with didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue, didselectrowatindexpath, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a problem with using SWRevealViewController. How to call prepare for segue in didSelectRowAtIndexPath? It is necessary because in tableView I have name of categories and some of this categories have its own subcategories. For example my list:

```
- category1
- category2
+ category3
- category4
```

So, when I click on + category3 I should see

```
- category1
- category2
+ category3
  - subcategory1
  - subcategory2
- category4
```

But I could not to do this because of prepareForSegue
Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section <= _categories.count) {
        GDCategory *category = [[_subCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        _gdCategory = category;
        if (category.subcategories.count > 0) {
            NSNumber *categoryId = @(category.dbId);
            if ([_selectedSubCategories containsObject:categoryId]) {
                [_selectedSubCategories removeObject:categoryId];
            } else {
                [_selectedSubCategories addObject:categoryId];
            }
            NSLog(@"There are %lu subcategories in %@", (unsigned long)category.subcategories.count, category.name);
            [self recalcSubcategories];
            [tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            //Here I should call prepareForSegue
        }
        NSLog(@"selected category is %@", category.name);
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // configure the destination view controller:
    if ( [sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] ) {
        UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
        GDCategoryVC *categoryVC = [navController childViewControllers].firstObject;
        if ( [categoryVC isKindOfClass:[GDCategoryVC class]] ) {
            categoryVC.selectedCategory = _gdCategory;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I could not to pass data throw VCs, because prepareForSegue call firstly. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//in prepareForSegue method

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

and you can get selected row value by using indexPath.row

Comment: Ok, thanks for an answer, but could you describe in detail what are you meaning, please?

Comment: I think u need to pass value from some array into categoryVC when  selecting a tableviewrow.. right?

Comment: ok..fine how did u set the segue to categoryVC?? is it from your tableviewcell of your viewcontroller?

Comment: From tableviewcell I set SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController to Navigation controller to categoryVC

Comment: ok.. remove that segue.. add segue from your viewcontroller to navigationcontroller

Comment: then in your didselectrow call  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seguename" sender:self];

Comment: in prepareforsegue  if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"seguename"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableviewname indexPathForSelectedRow];
       
        categoryVC.selectedCategory =   [arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 0):

To change the current View you shouldn't call prepareForSegue. Use performSegueWithIdentifier instead. PrepareForSegue will be called automatically. 
If you want to pass the UITableViewCell as sender you need to call the cellForRowAtIndexPath from your TableViewDataSource

```
else {
            //Here I should call prepareForSegue
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] //call self if dataSource is implement in your class
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:cell] // Insert your identifier for the wished Segue
        }
```

With SWRevealController it can happen that the View did changed like it should, but the RevealMenu is still visible. For that issue you can call:

```
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
```